# What is meant by "analogous reactions" in the Bell-Evans Polanyi Principle?

Tags: thermodynamics, reaction-control

The BEP principle says that for analogous reactions, enthalpy change and activation energy are linearly related. What is meant by analogous reactions?

Eg. For electrophilic addition of HBr to pent-1-ene, two products (2 or 1-bromopentane) are possible. But carbocation for formation of 2-bromo-pentane is more stable, so 2-bromopentane is also more stable than 1-bromopentane. Here, BEP applies.

But then for E2 elimination of HBr from 2-bromobutane, the transition state leading to formation of but-1-ene is more stable than that for formation of but-2-ene, although the product but-1-ene itself is less stable. Here, it seems to contradict BEP principle? Are these not considered analogous reactions? If so, why?

Comment: The 'analogous' would refer to, for example, HBr + pent-1-ene and the analogous reaction HBr + hex-1-ene.  These two _analogous_ reactions are in the same family of reactions, HBr addition to alkenes.